# apt-get is broken, udev, update-initramfs and insserv seem to be the problem

Tags: debian, apt, udev

When I am trying to do a simple

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or something that involve installing package

```
sudo apt-get install <mypackage>
```

I keep getting the same error message :

```
[truncated ...]
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u5) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service udev
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/tigon/tg3_tso5.bin for module tg3
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/tigon/tg3_tso.bin for module tg3
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/tigon/tg3.bin for module tg3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried quite a few things to repair this, be it
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall udev
Or trying something like going into synaptic, trying to delete residual config softwares...

So far nothing worked; I also tried to download udev package, and then

```
dpkg -i --force-install /path/to/udev
```

But no matter what, I keep getting back to the same issue, AKA problems with udev.

I also tried to enable moutkernfs, but doing so tell me that it is masked. "No" problem, I unmask it, then try to enable it, but it still says that it is masked.

What can I do ?

EDIT:
Here is systemctl output, as requested

```
systemctl status mountkernfs
● mountkernfs.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insserv` thinks `mountkernfs` is disabled, which basically means that there are no links to `/etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh` in the `/etc/rc?.d` directories. As a result it refuses to enable `udev` (which depends on `mountkernfs`)...

To fix that, run

```
insserv mountkernfs.sh
```

which will restore the default links, in `/etc/rcS.d`. (The `-v` option gives more details if necessary.) Then `insserv` will consider that `mountkernfs` is enabled, so `udev` can also be activated.

As to why things ended up that way, I don't know...